# How to make Android Studio build necessary module when click run

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have a Android app which have two modules. First module is app (main module) and second module is an external library.

Every time I click Start app in Android Studio, gradle will build two modules (I'm not sure) and install app into genymotion. It takes me a lot of time (5 - 6 min) because the external module is very big.

I want to create a gradle task which only build my main module and install app into genymotion.

Is it possible?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the build tab there are two options mainly, one is **make project** and the other one depends on which module is currently selected. That means if you have selected the app module it would say **make module app** and if you have selected the external library instead it would be like **make module external library**

So you should just select your app module and click on **make module app**

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can enable instant run option in Android Studio. File->Settings->Build,Execution, Deployment->Instant Run and Enable it. This will only build the most recent code changes made to your project.